# Re add mxml element once it has been removed from display object

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have some MXML elements which i would like to remove and add to a parent element. Unfortunately I am constrained to removing the MXML object as this is handled by the custom component. So is there any way to reinstate a removed MXML element back into the display list?

Sorry if this is an old question, or am i missing something obvious.

A

Answer (score 0):

You have to store a reference to the component as a variable somehow.

```
var myComponent : UIComponent = mxmlID
this.removeChild(myComponent)
```

Then at some future point you can do this:

```
this.addChild(myComponent);
```

Nothing about using custom components should affect this at all.  I'm unclear what happens behind the scenes with MXML set IDs that are removed; but I assume they are garbage collected and you won't be able to access the same component w/ the same ID.

Comment: What's the need to store in a separate variable? Wouldn't just `this.removeChild(mxmlId);` work as well? `mxmlId` would continue to be a public variable and be accessible even if it is removeChild'ed.

Comment: of course!! why didn't I check this? The mxmlid does still exist.
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: removeChild(mxmlID) should work fine. I just wasn't sure you'd be able to add it back in.  IT sounds like it worked for you.  To find out what really goes on, use the "-keep" compiler argument and review the ActionScript. Does addChild(mxmlID) create a new instance?  Or is the old instance kept around?